# Subscribe an email with MailChimp API 3.0 in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, mailchimp

I'm trying to subscribe a user to my MailChimp list from Ruby 1.9.3. I've got the following code:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'digest/md5'

class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :email
    validates :email, :confirmation => true

    before_create :chimp_subscribe


    def chimp_subscribe
        api_key = "my api key"
        list_id = "my list id"
        dc = "my data center"
        member_id = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(self.email)

        uri = URI.parse("https://" + dc + ".api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/" + list_id + "/members/" + member_id)
        req = Net::HTTP::Put.new(uri.path)
        req.body = { "email" => self.email, "status" => 'subscribed' }.to_json
        req.content_type = "application/json"

        res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
            http.request(req)
        end
    end
end
```

Before creating a new `Email`, it runs `chimp_subscribe`. Unfortunately, it breaks in the request block, with `Errno::ECONNRESET`, meaning that MailChimp is resetting my connection.

Am I missing some MailChimp API parameter in here? I'm struggling to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server you are requesting is HTTPS, so you should use SSL.

You should first require it:

```
require 'openssl'
```

Then make your request like this:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE # You should use VERIFY_PEER in production
res = http.request(req)
```

Comment: followup: I'm getting 401 Unauthorized. I added an Authorization header with "username:apikey" as its value, but the 401 persists. Any tips?